# Laravel + Eloquent ORM: HasManyThrough OrderBy TableC.column2

Tags: php, database, laravel, orm, eloquent

> Table A = Inventory | Table B = ItemAssociation | Table C = ItemValue

I have Table A, B and C. A and B have a one-to-one relationship, B and C have a one to one relationship. I'm currently using the HasManyThrough relationship to arrive at this:

```
public function item(){
    return $this->hasManyThrough('App\ItemValue','App\ItemAssociation','id','id');
}
```

And in my controller:

```
public function orm(){
    $inventory = Inventory::getAssocBySteamID(76561198124900864)->get();
    $i = 0;
    foreach($inventory as $inv){
        $this->data[$i] = $inv->item()->get();
        $i++;
    }
    return $this->data;
}
```

Where Inventory::getAssocBySteamID:

```
public static function getAssocBySteamID($id){
    return SELF::where('steamid64','=',$id);
}
```

This returns all the data I need, however, I need to order this by a column in Table C, the ItemValue model.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can add ->orderBy('TableName', 'desc') to the getAssocBySteamID function.
Or to the query in the Orm() function before the ->get()

Also for Where clauses in Eloquent's QB you don't need the "="sign. You can just do where('steamid',$id)

Answer (score 0):

Do not use static function use scopes. Try using join query like this:

```
// Inventory model method
public function scopeAssocBySteamID($query, $id) {
    $query->where('steamid64', $id)
        ->join('ItemValue'. 'ItemValue.id', '=', 'Inventory.ItemValue_id')
        ->select('Inventory.*')
        ->orderBy('ItemValue.item_price')
}
```

And then:

```
public function orm(){
    $inventory = Inventory::assocBySteamID(76561198124900864)->get();
    $i = 0;
    foreach($inventory as $inv){
        $this->data[$i] = $inv->item()->get();
        $i++;
    }
    return $this->data;
}
```

Check all table and field names befor testing this example.

Comment: This works, thanks! However, it's still not sorting by the column item_price in Table C (ItemValue).

Comment: I put it in the edit above. Check if You have it: `->orderBy('ItemValue.item_price')`

Comment: Still not working... It changes the order, but it doesn't have any relevance to ItemValue.item_price... Strange

Comment: Ok can You show me few item_price examples and tell me what type is this field in database?

Comment: See here: [screenshot](http://prnt.sc/ay0zzv) , it's a numerical value in the DB: `average_price NUMERIC(8,2),`

Comment: So whats your main problem now :) because I'm totally confused

Comment: So I can order by volume, but I cannot order by `average_price`, which is what I need.

Comment: Still stuck with this, any ideas?